# Cant get modal to work on Meteor app

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Good day, I am currently trying to do something extremely simple, to let a modal window appear on a click of a button in Meteor.

So I created a JS file on the lib folder called Sessions where I wrote this code

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
Session.setDefault('showAhorroGen',false);}
```

Which first allows me to set the Session as false as a default and when I click it , it will become true and show the dialog.

So then in my client folder I created an event to hear for when the  button is clicked, and a helper to return the session.

```
 Template.menu.events({
        'click .ahorro': function(event,tmpl){
            Session.set('showAhorroGen',true)

        }
});


Template.products.helpers({
    showAhorroGen : function(){
    return Session.get('showAhorroGen');
}})
```

In my HTML I added the following code, to render the template with the modal if the session **showAhorroGen** is true.

```
<h3> Cálcula tu ahorro gratis  <button type='button' class='btn  btn-danger ahorro'>Aquí</button></h3>
    </div>
    {{#if showAhorroGen}}
        {{> ahorroGen}}
    {{/if}}
```

and finally the template, for testing reasons is only the bootstrap modal example

```
<template name='ahorroGen'>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Why does the modal window does not appear?

Comment: After reading your question twice I still have no idea what your issue is. Indeed, what went wrong? The modal doesn't show up? At first glance your code seems fine.

Comment: The modal does not show up. So, my question, is why is the modal not appearing?

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly then.

Comment: Does this modification fits the question accordingly?

Comment: Yep, it's perfect. Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that now you've written code that dynamically inserts the HTML code for the modal, but in Bootstrap, you need to activate the modal in order to show it, for example by executing the following JavaScript code: `$("#myModal").modal()`.

**EDIT**

The easiest way to solve it is by adding the following piece of JavaScript code:

```js
Template.ahorroGen.onRendered(function(){
   $("#myModal").modal()
})
```

Comment: Ok, could you please elaborate more? I didnt get it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're targeting the wrong template with your event, and helper definition.

You're currently targeting the "menu" template in your event, and the "product" template for the helper. These should both be targeting the same template.

Comment: I changed the target and still it is not working. The modal window is not appearing.